# Reading and writing to x86 and x64 registry keys from the same application

Tags: c#, .net, registry, x86-64

I am running my application compiled as x86, and it is running on 64 bit Windows.

In order to fix a problem with ClickOnce file associations I want to read some CLSID values from the x86 view of the registry and then write them to the x64 view.

To be clear, this means that from an x86 application I want to *simultaneously* read from the x86 registry view and then write to the x64 registry view. I want to take the values I find under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{my clsid}` and write them to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{my clsid}`.

How should I do this? Using a `RegistryView` is producing unexpected results. For example, this `OpenSubKey` call returns null:

```
keyPath = @"Software\Classes\CLSID\" + clsid;
var regularx86View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
var regularClassKey = regularx86View.OpenSubKey(keyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
```

If I use `RegistryView.RegistryDefault` or `RegistryView.Registry64` instead it returns the key - but I would expect it to return null when using `Registry64` because that key doesn't exist in the x64 view and there should be no redirection taking place.

Is using a `RegistryView` the appropriate thing to be doing, or should I be using the WinAPI directly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding what you're asking but if you're running in a 32bit process then all your keys will be in the `Wow6432Node\xxxxx` node anyway. So if you tried to copy them from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{my clsid}` (and didn't specify the 64 bit view manually) to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{my clsid}` you would be copying the same values. This code should work:

```
keyPath = @"Software\Classes\CLSID\" + clsid;
var regularx86View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32);
// Note this calls HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{my clsid}:
var regularClassKey = regularx86View.OpenSubKey(keyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree); 

var regularx64View = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
// Note this calls HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{my clsid}:
var regularClassKey = regularx64View.OpenSubKey(keyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);
```

Comment: Thanks @Zipper, your answer was correct - I had things back to front in my mind (it wasn't obvious that Registry32 was picking up stuff from the Wow6432Node node).

Comment: @Zipper I have some doubts. Can 32bit application get access to 64bit hive of registry. I am not sure about this.

Comment: Just a side note: if you are using a .NET before .NET4, this approach will not work for you..

Comment: @Faisal Hafeez: yes, from a 32bit application on a 64bit system you can access the 64bit registry, I just tried to be sure :)