# Passing path to RegistryKey but getting back different path instead

Tags: c#, registry, regedit, registrykey

Using RegistryKey in C# I'm trying to find a specific software in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

But even though I pass this path to SubKey, I get back this path instead:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Code:

```
public void GetSubKeys(RegistryKey SubKey)
{
    List<string> viList = new List<string>();
    string[] val = SubKey.GetSubKeyNames();
    foreach (var VARIABLE in val)
    {
        RegistryKey SubKey1 = SubKey.OpenSubKey(SubKey + @"\" + VARIABLE);
        if (SubKey1.ToString().Contains("MySw"))
        {
            viList.Add(VARIABLE);
        }
     }
}
```

I know that because I'm searching for a specific SW which is not located in the `WOW6432Node` registry key, but in the other key, and there are various sw which are shown in the `WOW6432Node` key and not in the first key...

How come?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you're running the program compiled as `x86`, not `Any CPU`?

Comment: It's due to registry redirection for 32bit processes vs. 64bit in windows. You need to use the [OpenBaseKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx) method where you specify 32bit or 64bit "view" of the registry. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13232372/5095502) is a fairy comprehensive answer. If you search around there are [others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15424697/5095502) too.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. all your links helped a lot and solved my problem!